# Remove the last character using strrchr and substr in PHP

Tags: php

User may enter abc.com/ instead of abc.com, so I want to do validation using `strchr`.

This works but looks strange

```
    if(strrchr($url, "/") == "/"){
        $url = substr($url, 0,-1);
        echo $url;
    }
```

Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: `strrchr` is useless in PHP, must easier ways to get what you want exist.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes - using the optional second argument to [`trim()` or `rtrim()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rtrim.php) you can specify a character list to trim off the end of a string.:

```
$url = rtrim($url, '/');
```

If the trailing `/` is present, it will be stripped and the string returned without it. If not present, the string will be returned in its original form.

```
// URL with trailing /
$url1 = 'example.com/';
echo rtrim($url1, '/');
// example.com

// URL without trailing 
$url2 = 'example.com';
echo rtrim($url2, '/');
// example.com

// URL with many trailing /
$url3 = 'example.com/////';
echo rtrim($url3, '/');
// example.com
```

Add additional characters into the string with `'/'` if you want to strip whitespace as well, as in `rtrim($url, ' /')`

If you merely want to test if the last character of the URL was `/`, you may do so with `substr()`

```
if (substr($url, -1) === '/') {
  // true
}
```

Comment: if there is no / at the end the rtrim will return false and do nothing?

Comment: @ivyong `rtrim()` will _remove_ the `/` from the end of the string and return a bare URL. Is that not your intent, to convert `example.com/` to `example.com` ?

Comment: @ivyong Please clarify exactly what you want to achieve, because I may have misunderstood. Do you intend to remove the trailing `/` or just verify its presence or non-presence?

Comment: remove the trailing. So if the url is abc.com, it will return false and my url is still abc.com

Comment: rtrim() alone will remove the `/` but won't return false if the string is unchanged. I still don't understand - is the end result you desire the string `abc.com` or `true/false` for the presence of the `/`?

Comment: string, not true and false. Thanks Micheal!